Joining 'fish shell' arguments into a single string with spaces
Sorry, this question is already answered for 'bash' here:
Joining bash arguments into single string with spaces.
in Fish, using "'$*'" leads to this error:
$* is not supported. In fish, please use $argv.
but I can't figure out how to join $argv elements to a single string with space between them.
I also tried the "${@}" solution, which also doesn't work.

You're looking for string join ' ' $argv -- docs
